# IIFE and objects in JS

Tags: javascript, class, iife

Trying to do this

```
/*Javeline Javascript simple forum API by Makerimages v1.0*/

(function(){

    Javeline={};
    alert("hia");
    Javeline.isNameSpace=true;
    alert("hia");
    Javeline.toString= function() { return "Javeline"; };

    Javeline.Application=Application();
    Javeline.Application.create();
    alert("appmade");

}());

function Application()
{
    function create()
    {
        Javeline.Application=this;
        alert(Javeline.Application);
    }
}
```

why wont the code not run  `Javeline.Application.create()` ?

also the toString returns everything on that line after the =

Comment: *Why won't the code not run* Do you mean "Why won't the code run?" Or do you not want `create` to run?

Comment: Because `Application` doesn't return anything, and certainly not an object with methods.

Comment: Meant "Why won't the code run?"  by the not run I wanted to just specify the part that wont work is javeline.Application.create()

Comment: Then how do I fix it?

Comment: `/*Javeline Javascript simple forum API by Makerimages v1.0*/

(function(){

 Javeline={};
 Javeline.isNameSpace=true;
 
 Javeline.Application=Application();
 alert(Javeline.Application)
 var a=Javeline.Application.create();
 alert("a");

}());
 
function Application()
{
 function create()
 {
  Javeline.Application=this;
  alert(Javeline.Application);
  
 }
 return this;
}`  makes it alert the Javeline.Application as [object Window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
Javeline.Application=new Application();

//....

function Application()
{
    this.create = function()
    {
        Javeline.Application=this;
        alert(Javeline.Application);
    }
}
```

Just calling `Application` will return `undefined`, since the function doesn't have a return statement. Calling it with the `new` keyword will give you a new object. However, to add the function `create` as a property to this new object, you have to declare it as a property of `this` inside of `create`.

Comment: doing this in the ^ file  `/*Javeline Javascript simple forum API by Makerimages v1.0*/

(function(){

 Javeline={};
 Javeline.isNameSpace=true;
 
 Javeline.Application= new Application();
 
}());
 

function Application()
{
 this.text="awd";

  this.create = function()
    {
     
        Javeline.Application=this;
        
    }
 
}` and this in another .js file `App=Javeline.Application.create();
alert(App.text);` both of which are brought together by index.html

Comment: index.html : `<html>
<head>
<title>Javeline Beginning</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/core/JavelineCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>` the alert is not shown